# Resolve generic interface with Windsor without knowing the type at compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, castle-windsor

With Windsor I can do this:

```
var validators = container.ResolveAll<IEntityValidator<Product>>();
```

But I don't know the type at compile. I need code more like this:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
var validators = container.ResolveAll<IEntityValidator<...type...>>();
```

Obviously, the code above is not near the correct solution. I'm guessing there's some relfection magic needed. If it's at all possible with Windsor. Is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might not be quite complete but it's possibly close to what you want to do:

```
var typeParam = obj.GetType();
var type = typeof(IEntityValidator<>).MakeGenericType(typeParam);
container.Resolve(type);
```

Comment: This is probably as close as I can get. Together with `validator.GetType().GetMethod("Validate").Invoke(validator, new[] {obj});` it works fine. But since I have to use reflection to call the method and I don't get strong typing I'll probably go another way. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can hand-craft the type you want using reflection. Something like this:

```
var wantedGenericParam = obj.GetType();
var genericType = typeof(IEntityValidator<>).MakeGenericType(wantedGenericParam);
var allValidators = container.ResolveAll(genericType);
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  What gets done by  `container.ResolveAll<IEntityValidator<Product>>()` is decided at compile time not at run time.  It is the execution that takes place at run time.

Comment: it's not possible to do it strongly typed, but possible in a non-strongly typed way.